# C Pointer: char to binary value

Tags: c, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int * bin(char a);

int main(void){
        char a='a';
        int k=0;
        int *binary;

        binary=bin(a);
        for(k=0; k<8; k++){
                printf("%d", *binary++); 
                printf("\n");      
        }

        return 0;
}
int *bin(char a){

        int i=0;
        int *arr;
        int output[8];
        char c=a;
        for (i = 0; i <8 ; ++i) {
                 output[8-i-1] = (a >> i) & 1;

        }
        arr=&output[0];
//              for (i = 0; i <8 ; ++i) {
//              printf("%d", output[i]);
//      }
//      printf("\n");

        return arr;
}
```

The ouptut should be the binary value of the char 'a'which is:
0
1
1
0
0
0
0
1

but i got this instead:
0
-1216804320
-1218095335
-1216804320
10
-1076423592
-1218208721
-1216804320

Is this a pointer problem?
How do i fix it so it would print the right answer? thx!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First error** I can notice is Scope problem, that *you are returning address of local variable* `output[8];`

```
 arr=&output[0];
 return arr;
```

That is wrong, *scope* of `output[]` is inside `bin()` function only.

You should *allocate memory* for `output[]` *dynamically if you want to access it outside* `bin()` function, like:

```
int *output = calloc(8, sizeof(int));
```

even you don't need extra variable just `return output` from bin()

I have corrected you code like below without much change:

```
int *bin(char a){
        int i=0;
        int *output = calloc(8, sizeof(int));
        for (i = 0; i <8 ; ++i) {
                 output[8-i-1] = (a >> i) & 1;
        }
        return output;
}
```

Notice removed unused variables `c` and `arr`

additionally, don't forgot to free dynamically allocated memory explicitly:

**Second** (*Notice*)  be aware of [`Memory Clobbering Error`](http://www.modula2.org/sb/sbd/index170.htm) because you are updating `binary` variable by `++` in `printf` function.

Just simple don't `free(binary);` it will produce run time error because you are modifying `binary` variable inside printf `*binary++`: first save return address in a extra pointer variable then free that. Like I am doing:

```
 b = binary=bin(a);      
 // loop 
  printf("%d", *binary++); 
 //             ^ changing binary variable to point new memory location  
 // after loop 
 free(b);
```

If you `free(binary)` then it would be wrong because you would free a memory location that is not allocated dynamically because your are changing `binary` variable.

get a working [**code here**](http://codepad.org/dBTwVUf1), read comments.

Comment: problem solved! And do i need to free the allocated memories?

Comment: @user1887339 Yes you should free memory explicitly in your case it will not problem but its needed it your allocate memory again and again in lengthy code. see how do I free memory once binary becomes unused in code: at codepad

Comment: @user1887339 Read todays [HOT question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15467298/how-far-can-memory-leaks-go) memory leak It help you to know why memory free required also read [wiki: Memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak)

Comment: after i added free(binary);, it prints the following:

Comment: *** glibc detected *** ./a.out: free(): invalid pointer: 0x09b32028 *** ======= Backtrace: =========
and ======= Memory map: ========

Comment: @user1887339 read updated answer my your are modifying `binary` variable so its pointing a new memory location.

Comment: ok and if i'm adding another method hex():                            int main(){
 char a='a';
int *binary, *hexadecimal ,*b, *c;
b=binary=bin(a);
c=hexadecimal =hex(binary);
free(b);
free(c);
}

int *hex(int *binary){
//operations
int *hexOutput = calloc(8, sizeof(int));
return hexOutput;
}     is the syntax correct, i need to create *c and add new calloc and free?

Comment: @user1887339 faith on what you understands. Read my updated answer there was other mistakes in your code that what `free(binary)` was producing error. Let me know if you need any more help on this.

Comment: @user1887339 Yes that is correct as I understands. See Please understand. by `free(binary)` you were free a memory location that was not reserved dynamically because you are changing `binary` by `++` in printf statment. If you don't you not need other variable.

Answer (score 4):

You're returning a pointer to a local variable (`arr`), whose contents are no longer valid when the function returns.  Use `malloc` instead:

```
int main(void){
        ...
        int *arr = bin(a);
        ...
        free(arr);
        return 0;
}

int *bin(char a){
        int *arr = malloc(8 * sizeof int);
        ...
        return arr;
}
```

Comment: You could pass the array into 'bin' also. No making sure of the matching free() being called.

Comment: @user1887339 faith on what you understands

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan: Did I say that? Now, for starters, this *is* a correct answer, contrary to the OP's claims. Furthermore, this answer *was* posted 45 Seconds before yours.

Comment: @bitmask I misunderstood your comment that the reason Yes RichieHindle's answer was first. but I had long discussion with OP..there was problem of free also. But I don't think 45 second before is big difference. I like answers on content base...any No problem.